# Azure Search failing with latest update of Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I had a package update today for Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime v2.3.12 to v2.3.13 and my search stopped working.  The symptoms are that the call to the client search would just hang.

Looking at the data through Fiddler, I can see the request go out and come back, but my output window is showing `Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll`.  I am not sure if this is related.

There is no timeout, no error and the call will continue indefinitely without returning anything.  This code has been working beautifully without issue until this package update.  I've ensured that this is the only package update and all other packages for Azure Search are at their latest versions.

Below is the call that is hanging.

```
SearchIndexClient.Documents.Search<T>(SearchBuild.ToString(), searchParams);
```

I'm trying to find out why this would happen and if there is a better way to find the true error.  My assumption is that the package is bad for `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime`

This is using a ASP.NET (not Core) app.   Using my class library in a Console app or with LINQPad seems to allow the project to run just fine.

Comment: Someone on our team is looking into this. In the future, please report Azure .NET SDK issues here: https://github.com/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues

Comment: Done, I've opened the following: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4711

Comment: Could you also let us know what type of app you are calling search from? Is it from Console, ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core? Thanks.

Comment: ASP.NET (not Core).  The call runs fine in a Console app after reading this, but just hangs on ASP.NET.  I've updated my original question to reflect that information.

Comment: Thanks. Apolgies for delay in answering this question. I will have a look first thing on Tuesday.

Comment: I have reproduced the issue. I confirm that this only occurs with the latest client runtime and not with the previous version. I have escalated this to the SDK team.

Comment: Same here: Upgraded from 2.3.12 -> 2.3.13 in an ASP.NET MVC project targeting .NET4.7 I've experienced the same "hang" mentioned above. Staying with 2.3.12 for now till 2.3.14 is released with fixed code as mentioned also in this GitHub thread: https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/2857#issuecomment-423597574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to the latest `Microsoft.Azure.Search` 5.0.3 resolves the issue.

Alternatively, updating to the latest `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure 3.3.16` resolves the issue, which brings in `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime 2.3.14` as a dependency.

For clarification, this is using a ASP.NET (not Core) app.

Comment: That version doesn't seem to exist: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime  I think you mean Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure, which brings in version 2.3.14 of Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The hang is the result of a bug in `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime`. The details are captured in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4711#issuecomment-420052345)

Answer (score 0):

I am Nate from Azure Search. I am unable to reproduce the issue unfortunately. I've tested the ClientRuntime v2.3.13 with Azure Search versions v5.0.0, v5.0.1, and the latest stable v5.0.2 using a sample application available at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/search-dotnet-getting-started/tree/master/DotNetHowTo. Can you reproduce the issue with the sample application? Feel free to reach out to me at nateko AT microsoft.com with more details if you'd like us to take a closer look at the service.

Nate

Comment: This app runs fine, but this is also a .NET Core console app.

Comment: Please differentiate between version updates suitable for *ONLY* Core and those for both Standard + Core. Having issues in different NuGet updates with updates applied for Core in a Standard project

Comment: @NitinSingh, I don't understand your question or statement?

Comment: While updating NuGet packages for some app, they stopped, only to find out that the newer version is for Core only. The docs don't differentiate and mention both versions. An example being the Cosmos db writer for Azure, 9.3.1 vs 9.1.1